# Bing flagging pages as Malware even after the malware or the pages were removed

Tags: bing, malware

Bing has flagged some pages on a site I manage as malware, these have been looked at and looks like there was some malware at some point but it's now since been removed.

It's also pointing to some pages which no longer exist saying there is malware on those.

Is there anything specific I need to do to get Bing to stop trying to access the removed pages and also deflag the pages that have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've cleaned up the pages submit a [reconsideration request to bing](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/hh204494.aspx), for the pages that no longer exist I'd return a [410 (gone) status message](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html) so the search engines no longer look for them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what Bing say [here](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2010/02/18/the-liability-of-loathsome-link-level-web-spam-sem-101.aspx) about if you're penalised for being spammy, but it sounds like it applies to malware too:

- Go to [Bing E-mail Support](https://support.discoverbing.com/eform.aspx?productKey=bingcontentremoval&ct=eformts&scrx=1) and fill out the form completely
- Select Content Inclusion Request from the drop-down list. A new drop-down will appear underneath.
- From the new drop-down list, select Reinclusion request.
- Write a clear and detailed explanation of what you have done to resolve the problem in the next text box. (You can prepare this in advance, and then copy and paste the text into the form.)
- Type the security code from the presented image into the text box below.
- Once the form is completed, click submit.

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial by sucuri:
http://blog.sucuri.net/2012/05/how-to-submit-infected-site-for-review-with-bing-blacklisting-authority.html.

You start by registering for [Bing webmaster tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/).